# Append to table function isn't working

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to append 2 datasets into one (both datasets have the same columns). To do this, I created a new dataset and set the destination table to an existing table that I want to append the new table to. However, when I do this, the dataset only contains data from the new table.

How can I make sure that the new dataset appends to the existing table?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly you did? show us and we will tell you what needs to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a table `dataset1.tableA` and a table in a difference dataset `dataset2.tableB`, both table have the same schema. You want to append the table `dataset2.tableB` to `dataset1.tableA`. Here is how you do it in **StandardSQL** via BQ UI:

- Set Destination Table: Dataset **dataset1** & table ID **tableA**
- Choose Write Preference: Append to table
- Run query: **SELECT * FROM `dataset2.tableB`**

Now in your table `dataset1.tableA` you should have data from `dataset2.tableB` appended.